# search a Text File for a sentence by date AND name

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to search my text-file for a sentence by date and by name. Then I want this sentence to load it to some textboxes in my form. I am new in VS but I know some things about C.
I have came up with this code:

```
string pattern =  dateTimePicker1Is.Text;
string pattern1 = _txtNameIs.Text;
IList<string> result = new List<string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Testet System\isto.txt"))
{
    string currentLine;
    while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
         if (currentLine.Contains(pattern))
         {
              if (currentLine.Contains(pattern1))
              {
                   result.Add(currentLine);

                   string[] tempArray = currentLine.Split(',');

                   _txtNameIs.Text = tempArray[0];
                   _txtSurnameIs.Text = tempArray[1];
                   _txtApokxT.Text = tempArray[2];
                   _txtApoktT.Text = tempArray[3];
                   _txtEpanxT.Text = tempArray[4];
                   _txtEpandT.Text = tempArray[5];
                   _txtApokkT.Text = tempArray[6];
                   _txtEpankT.Text = tempArray[7];
                   _txtApoksT.Text = tempArray[8];
                   _txtEpansT.Text = tempArray[9];
                   _txtGenSun.Text = tempArray[10];
                   break;
             }
             else
             {
                   MessageBox.Show("There are no records!");
             }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the search button it loads me all the data that I need, but if I have the same name and different date a message-box pops up and tells 'there are no records'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is better way doing this:

```
string pattern =  dateTimePicker1Is.Text;
string pattern1 = _txtNameIs.Text;
string pathToFile = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Testet System\isto.txt";
List<string> result = new List<string>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile))
{
   if (line.Contains(pattern) && line.Contains(pattern1))
   {
       result.Add(line);

       string[] tempArray = line.Split(',');

       if(tempArray.Length >= 11)
       {
           _txtNameIs.Text = tempArray[0];
           _txtSurnameIs.Text = tempArray[1];
           _txtApokxT.Text = tempArray[2];
           _txtApoktT.Text = tempArray[3];
           _txtEpanxT.Text = tempArray[4];
           _txtEpandT.Text = tempArray[5];
           _txtApokkT.Text = tempArray[6];
           _txtEpankT.Text = tempArray[7];
           _txtApoksT.Text = tempArray[8];
           _txtEpansT.Text = tempArray[9];
           _txtGenSun.Text = tempArray[10];
           break; 
       }  
   }        
}
```

It is better to show message if the list count is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `There are no records` error should happen

1. AFTER the while statement
2. IF no matches were found

Right?

So put if there was a match found in a bool, and then after the while if !IsMatchFound then throw your error.